# Center vertically img responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

Is there any method for vertically center a resposnive img without know height and width and without using display: table or position: absolute/relative?

The specific problem is that I am using bootstrap carousel and I want to center img responsive in different resolutions. So I can't use position attribute because the carousel has this attribute and bootstrap use display: table, so I can't use this.

I don't know the dimensions of the image because there are added dinamycally with PHP

I try to put a div container with fixed height attribute, this works great in large screens but in smaller resolutions this is not good because the img is very tall.

How can I do?

Comment: Example with Flexbox: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/KQjyP/

Comment: I try flexbox but in Windows Phone and Android the img is in the top of the div, not in the center :S

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to the CSS of the image:

```
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
display:block;
position:relative;
```

Comment: It only centers the image horizontally

Comment: Yes, sorry. You need to use margin-top and margin-bottom:50%. I've used the code below and it worked.         '<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.bigbox img{
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 margin-top:50%;
 margin-bottom:50%;
  margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;

}
body{
 height:auto;
}
 
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="bigbox">
<img src="http://www.xxxxxxxx.co.uk/images/box.png" width="139" height="151"/> 
</div><!--end of bigbox class-->


</body>
</html>
'