# img-responsive doesn't center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need some help. 
img-responsive doesn't centers with this code.

```
div.container-main {
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

Then the HTML code is this one

```
  <div class="container-main">  
  <section class="main">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/bio.png" alt="Microscópio Óptico">
  </section>
```

Any help? I've already seen [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697400/center-vertically-img-responsive) but didn't worked for me. 
Without img-responsive it's working excellent. 
I'm using Bootstrap.

Comment: weird. I tried it but it's going to the left all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pleasantly easy fix. Because .img-responsive from Bootstrap already sets `display: block`, you can use `margin: 0 auto` to center the image:

```
.img-responsive {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you're great. I'm kind of a newbie to Bootstrap, HTML and CSS, so thanks. I appreciate it. It worked.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new also on StackOverflow.